# java spark map function

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a map function that needs to be defined separately in my spark application

```
public final class App {
  private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("JavaWordCount")
      .getOrCreate()      
      ;
    System.out.println("hello");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(5);
    data.add("test.jpg");    
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = jsc.parallelize(data);
    rdd.map(tf_func);

    spark.stop();
  }
  public static String tf_func(){
      return "Hello";

  }
}
```

The above code does not able to recognize the defined function.

Answer (score 0):

[`JavaRDD.map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#map-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function-) takes a [`Function`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function.html) object.

```
 static <R> JavaRDD<R>  map(Function<T,R> f)
```

You cannot pass arbitrary method and expect it to work.